# When I try to call a mode_set operator from one of these handlers, the traceback blender crashes

Tags: python, add-on, development

I tryied to come with a elegant solution fot easily removing handlers from blender.

I was thinking in something like that.
The cool part is that in this case you can have independent namespaces for each handler that is a instance of class.

But I would like to hear from the experient addon writers if that gona work well, I find handlers a bit scary to work with.

like:
when I try to call an mode_set operator from one of these handlers, the traceback freak out and blender craches.

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

class WrappingHandler:

    def __init__(self, handler_list = None):

        self.setup()
        self.handler_list = handler_list
        if handler_list is not None:
            print("handler appended")
            handler_list.append(self.wrapper)

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, scene):
        pass

    def destroy(self):
        self.handler_list.remove(self.wrapper)

    @persistent
    def wrapper(self, scene):
        return self.__call__(scene)

class AutoDestructibleHandler(WrappingHandler):


    def __call__(self, scene):

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")

        self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AutoDestructibleHandler(bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre)
```

Comment: okay, I'll do that.

Comment: I find using a prefix on my handler method names and `[hander.remove(f) for f in hander if f.__name__.startswith("PREFIX")]` to remove them all, is a rather bulletproof, if not elegant, solution,